# Best way to implement UI Router Hierarchy /category/category/product

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

What's the best way to make something like this work in UI Router?

```
/category/product

/category/category/product
```

for example:

```
/telephones/apple/iphone4/product
```

So I have a product page that can contain inside one or more categories.
How do you do this in UI Router?

```
.state('product',{
    url: '/:categoryFirst/:product',
    templateUrl: '/partials/product.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl as product',
})


.state('product',{
    url: '/:categoryFirst/:categorySecond/:product',
    templateUrl: '/partials/product.html',
    controller: 'ProductCtrl as product',
})
```

Don't have much code because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [UI router sample app](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/) or [new sample app](http://ui-router.github.io/sample-app/#/mymessages) code to start creating your code. Those app's sources are available here: https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app.

And they seem to have complex enough level of routing to find your needs.

Comment: Thnx.this helped me a lot :)